# char * assignment: What's wrong with this code?

Tags: c, string, char, segmentation-fault, lldb

When I run into these code in **lldb**, I found it always goes `*wchar_string[0] = character;` this line and never loop out, 
This code gives Segmentation fault: 11.

This code, what's wrong?

```
wchar_t *wchar_string[1];
*wchar_string[0] = character;
wcstombs(retstring, (const wchar_t *)wchar_string, 6);
```

Comment: What is `character`?

Comment: @ForceBru character is of type wchar_t

Comment: It takes two arguments, wchar_t character, char *retstring, convert character to string into retstring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want

```
wchar_t wchar_string[2];
wchar_string[0] = character;
wchar_string[1] = 0;
```

You've already got an array.  You don't need any pointers, so you don't want those `*` characters.

Answer (score 2):

`*wchar_string[1]` is an array of length 1, containing a single pointer to `wchar_string`. Although each element of the array can point to anything, initially the pointers do not point to anything. In other words, their values are undefined, meaning that *dereferencing* them (i.e. applying the asterisk operator) is *undefined behavior*. That is why you see a segfault.

To fix this problem, allocate some memory to the `wchar_string[0]` object before making an assignment. An allocation could be static, dynamic, or automatic; the important thing is that the memory needs to be allocated *before* accessing it.

```
wchar_t str0[7];
wchar_t *wchar_string[1];
wchar_string[0] = str0; // could use &str0[0], too
*wchar_string[0] = character;
```